Issues Installing APK for Android App Testing: Extracts Files Instead of Installing
I'm currently working on testing my Android application across various devices and encountered an issue with the installation process of the APK file. After building the APK in Android Studio, I shared it with different devices to test. However, instead of the expected direct installation, the devices are extracting the files contained within the APK, preventing the app from installing properly.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or can offer insight into what I might be missing in the installation process?

How do you install the APK onto the test devices? The in my opinion best way for adb enabled devices is adb install <apkfile>.

Previously, I was distributing the app via other applications. However, when I install the app using a USB cable, there are no problems and the installation is successful. The only issue arises when attempting to share the APK through other apps.
